# iOS UITableViewCell autosizing bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've a `UITableViewCell` designed with `.xib` that use cell autosizing. In iOS 9 works well, but in iOS 8 cell doesn't expands itself, and the label inside remains with 1 line of text. If the cell go away from the screen and the came back (i.e. after a scrolling) all label are ok.

Ideas? I think this is an iOS 8 bug.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had faced same problem. If your constraints are set properly you need to set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for each `UILabel` you have in cell, just before you return the cell. Here is some example code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.lblTitle.text = @"N";
    cell.lblDetails.text = @"bla bla";
    cell.lblOther.text = @"other text";


    // Configure the cell...
    CGfloat leftPading =// "your logo width + spacing between logo and label"
    CGfloat rightPading = //your label trailing space
    cell.lblTitle.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds)-(leftPading +rightPading);
    cell.lblDetails.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds)-(leftPading +rightPading);
     [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    return cell;
    }
```

[Have a look at this to know how to put constrains properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

hope this will helps you.

Answer (score -1):

That depends on your code but there's a really simple way to do this

```
1. Define auto layout constraints for your prototype cell
2. Specify the estimatedRowHeight of your table view
3. Set the rowHeight of your table view to UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

a good explanation can be found here http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

edit:well, I guess the joke is on me for assuming the question was about swift instead of obj-c(didn't notice the tag).
Because I think my answer is still useful(for other people that is)...I'm going to leave it here.

Answer (score -1):

you need to added table view delegated methods for height of the cell.

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50.0f;
}
```

It will work. If there any issue that might be issue on auto layout constraints.